# How to display text with many lines inside a ScrolledComposite?

Tags: java, windows, swt, styledtext

I have a `StyledText` widget (SWT) inside a `ScrolledComposite` that should display the content of a log file. Unfortunately the log file has thousands of lines in it so that I came to the point where the widget cuts off the text after ~ 2200 lines.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510579/does-swt-styledtext-have-a-height-limit) that refers to [this report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333111) that states that there is a height limitation for widgets in windows and my theory is that I have reached that limit.

My question is how I can deal with this. What is the workaround for displaying text with that many lines in it?

EDIT:
I found out that this does only happen, if I use the `StyledText` inside a `ScrolledComposite`. If I use the plain `StyledText` there is no problem.

Here's the code to reproduce:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class StyledTextLimit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        ScrolledComposite scrollComp = new ScrolledComposite(shell,
                SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

        StyledText text = new StyledText(scrollComp, SWT.NONE);
        text.setSize(100, 500);

        scrollComp.setContent(text);
        scrollComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrollComp.setExpandVertical(true);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            builder.append(i);

            builder.append(" ");

            for (int j = 'a'; j < 'a' + 200; j++) {
                builder.append((char) j);
            }

            builder.append("\n");
        }

        text.setText(builder.toString().trim());

        scrollComp.setMinSize(text.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));


        // shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need to wrap the `StyledText` into a `ScrolledComposite`. The `StyledText` shows scrollbars on its own when necessary.

I suggest using the `StyledText` without a `ScrolledComposite`.

The `StyledText` certainly also has a limit on what text it is capable to hold. This limit, however, should be much higher than 2200 lines. If `StyledText` still overflows, then you'll have to truncate the log to be shown.

Comment: The problem is that I have a line counter to the left of the `StyledText` as a `Label` so that I think I still need the `ScrolledComposite`...

Comment: If you don't mind the dependency on `org.eclipse.jface.text`, you could use a `SourceViewer` which wraps a `StyledText` and allows showing _rulers_ with line numbers.

Comment: Okay as you can see in my edited question I found out that the problem seems to be the `ScrolledComposite` and not the `StyledText`...

Comment: For anybody with the same problem: I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057442/java-swt-show-line-numbers-for-styledtext) solution to add the line numbers as the `SourceViewer` was too complicated for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

Although @Rüdiger Herrmann helped me fixing my problem I still feel that I should help those who might come to the same problem as I did without the possibility of getting rid of the `ScrolledComposite`.

Therefore I want to link [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851955/swt-scrolledcomposite-cutting-off-information) that deals with the `ScrolledComposite` problem.